# Dedicated server: How to install OpenCL for Nvidia GTX 1080 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS minimal?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, gpu, opencl

I downloaded [this script](https://software.intel.com/file/555660/download%20Edit), provided by Intel and installed OpenCL without any problems.

```
$ mv install_OCL_driver.sh_.txt install_OCL_driver.sh
$ chmod 755 install_OCL_driver.sh
$ sudo su
$ ./install_OCL_driver.sh install
```

At the end of the installation it said, I should now boot into the patched 4.7 Kernel. I did successfully.

[Image of the output after successfull installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEkps.png)

Then I booted into the suggested kernel and verified that I did:

`uname -r` -> `4.7.0.intel.r5.0`

`uname -a` -> `Linux Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal 4.7.0.intel.r5.0 #1 SMP Sat Dec 9 14:10:02 CET 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

But the "[System Analyzer Utility](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/mss-sys-analyzer-linux)" outputs "FAIL" for GPU. [See this image for the output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89XtO.png).

Then I tried to install `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run` and got this warnings:

***WARNING: nvidia-installer was forced to guess the X library path '/usr/lib' and X module path '/usr/lib/xorg/modules'; these paths were not queryable from the system. If X fails to find the NVIDIA X driver module, please install the `pkg-config` utility and the X.Org SDK/development package for your distribution and reinstall the driver.***

***WARNING: Unable to find a suitable destination to install 32-bit compatibility libraries. Your system may not be set up for 32-bit compatibility. 32-bit compatibility files will not be installed; if you wish to install them, re-run the installation and set a valid directory with the --compat32-libdir option.***

Then I rebooted and started the "System Analyzer Utility" again.
This is the result:

[Result (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPMpO.png)

I am pretty much lost and don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are you not already running with the nvidia proprietary drivers? If so and you install the `clinfo` package and run clinfo in a terminal, what is the output? Please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: Also, if you want to use the 1080 for OpenCL (most anything would run with CUDA directly instead, for NVidia cards), why are you messing with the Intel bits?

Comment: I need OpenCL for the GPU computing I am planning to do. I tried with the proprietary drivers. They are also installed. Here's the output of `clinfo`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26146854/

What do you mean with "messing with the Intel bits"?

Comment: This is an additional output from the binary I want to use: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26147021/

But when trying to choose the GPU as device, I get this errors: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26147028/

Comment: The link to the error wasn't complete. This is the complete error: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26147057/

Comment: I mean your question is all about the Intel OpenCL stuff and tools, outside of saying you downloaded the driver from NVidia (the drivers are installable via apt btw). Please [edit] your questin to include the output, not just links to pastebins. If you don't want to use OpenCL on the Intel GPU, but only NVidia, I'd suggest removing the Intel OpenCL ICD.